# Multidimensional array with additional boolean

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I am still get the grasp of PHP arrays and the proper way of doing them. Basically I have a product that has a set of shared options but also options specific to the model. Right now I have it like this

```
$divers = array(
        'models' => array("Launch 9.5","Launch 12.5","Launch 15.5", "Launch 18.5"),
        'lengths' => array(47.5, 47, 46.5, 46, 45.5, 45, 44.5, 44, 43.5, 43, 42.5, 42),
    );
```

So each model has the same lengths but I need to add a boolean (true or false) to the model as well. So 9.5 would be true but 12.5 would be false (basically we have a certain option in 9.5 but we dont in 12.5). How would I do this? Is there a better way to set up the array? I chose this way so I can do foreach loops that spit out form elements.

Comment: So what is the problem? Add those booleans if you need. 'models' => array("Launch 9.5" => true, "Launch 12.5" => false,"Launch 15.5" => true, "Launch 18.5" => false). Or i misunderstood you?

Comment: I wasnt aware I could just add it on. to access the bool do I just use `$divers[models][]`?

Comment: To access those bools you should provide key of which you want to access: example $divers['models']['Launch 9.5'] will return true(for my example in first comment) $divers['models']['Launch 12.5'] will return false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the array values you already have as array keys instead, then add a boolean as the value.

```
$divers = array(
  'models' => array("Launch 9.5" => true,"Launch 12.5" => false,"Launch 15.5", "Launch 18.5"),
  'lengths' => array(47.5, 47, 46.5, 46, 45.5, 45, 44.5, 44, 43.5, 43, 42.5, 42),
);

foreach($divers['models'] as $model) {
  if($model === true) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works! But how do I access the "launch 9.5" now to echo the name? Before in my loop `$model` returned the name, now it just returns a key.

Comment: @Packy solution to this problem is covered in my answer,where you have access to the names, like "lauch 9.5"

Comment: @Packy In the foreach example I used, use `as $name => $value` instead of `as $model`, and you will have access to both.

Answer (score 0):

If all models have all available `length` values, you may have this:

```
$divers = array(
    "Launch 9.5"    =>    array(
                             "bool"      => false, 
                             "option"    => true
                          ),
    "Launch 12.5"   =>    array(
                             "bool"      => false, 
                             "option"    => true
                          ),
    "Launch 15.5"   =>    array(
                             "bool"      => false, 
                             "option"    => true
                          )
);

$length = array(47.5, 47, 46.5, 46, 45.5, 45, 44.5, 44, 43.5, 43, 42.5, 42);
```

But If don't share all the `length` values (that is more likely), you may have this:

```
$divers = array(
    "Launch 9.5"    =>    array(
                             "bool"      => false, 
                             "option"    => true, 
                             "length"    => array( 47.5, 47, 50 ) 
                          ),
    "Launch 12.5"   =>    array(
                             "bool"      => false, 
                             "option"    => true, 
                             "length"    => array( 45, 43, 49 ) 
                          ),
    "Launch 15.5"   =>    array(
                             "bool"      => false, 
                             "option"    => true, 
                             "length"    => array( 46.5, 48, 50 ) 
                          )
);
```

**What is the measure**

The measures to consider while deciding what array structure to use, are:

- **manipulation**

  consider how much data you may need to use at once, like in `for` loops
- **redundancy**

  don't repeat data which is shared among all entities the same
- **`key => value` pair**

  Often you have a `for` or `foreach` loop which will be used to loop through elements. There you need to have a simple access to `key`s and `value`s, so try not to complicate your structure.

**EXAMPLE**

```
foreach( $divers as $d_name => $d_value ){
    echo $d_name;           // Launch 9.5
    echo $d_value['bool'];  // false
}
```